# How to inject into a html another html along with it css file using the content scripts?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I'm completely confused how to inject an entire html to another html using content scripts in chrome extension.

I'm currently doing

```
document.body.innerHTML += 'html';
```

But that only helps when injecting some minor html code, and not an entire html file, which has its own css and js files.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: General solution: use iframes. NEVER use `document.body.innerHTML += '..';`, because it will break almost every dynamic site on the internet...

Comment: @RobW When I saw the code used by Pocket, it was injecting code into the html div, rather than an iFrame.

Comment: @RobW I am taking the Pocket example, as that is something that I want to achieve and a bit more.

Comment: `.innerHTML += ` will remove all event listeners and invalidate any previous element references. It should only be used on content you "own". `<body>` elements in arbitrary web pages do certainly not meet that criterium.

Answer (score 1):

If you have been trying something similar to loading one html file into another, then the ***JQuery*** `load()` method might help:

```
$( "#mydiv" ).load( "thepageIwannaload.html" );
```

You can simply create the html you want to load as a separate html file and load it into your file.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, have you tried some ajax?  something along the lines of...

```
var xmlRequestObject;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
xmlRequestObject=new XMLHttpRequest();
}

xmlRequestObject.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlRequestObject.readyState==4 && xmlRequestObject.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("elementID").innerHTML=xmlRequestObject.responseText;
}
}

xmlRequestObject.open("GET","document.html",true);

xmlRequestObject.send();
```

this ajax would work for the main browsers and substitute the arguements for the correct ones obviously.  Hope I understood your question correctly.